# how to get the value of multiple unselected checkboxes in php?

Tags: php

i tried for selected chcekboxes but

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="C/C++"><label>C/C++</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Java"><label>Java</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="PHP"><label>PHP</label><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//to run PHP script on submit
        if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
        foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
        echo $selected."</br>";
        }
      }
    }
?>
```

how to get the value for unselected checkboxes?

Comment: Please note that your unselected checkboxes won't be available in your POST data. Your POST will contain only the ones which are checked.

Comment: but i require value of multiple unselected checkbox?? what is the solution for that??

Comment: but i required the value of unselected checkbox??? what is the solution

Comment: Please take a look at my answer. It will solve your purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that your unselected checkboxes won't be available in your POST data. Your POST will contain only the ones which are checked.

You can store all possible options in the `$options`, and all the checked options in `$checked`.

We can find the unchecked options by using  [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) i.e by finding the difference between `$options` and `$selected`.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //to run PHP script on submit
    $options = array("C/C++", "Java", "PHP");
    $checked = isset($_POST['check_list']) ? $_POST['check_list'] : array();
    $unchecked = array_diff($options, $checked);
    /* Other code */
 }
```